# How to derive this Sobolev-type inequality in $\mathbb R^3$?

Tags: sobolev-spaces

Does anyone know a simple way to derive the following inequality for smooth, compactly supported functions in $\mathbb R^3$?

$$ \max \,\{ |u(x)| \mid x \in \mathbb R^3 \} \;\leq\;  
K\|\, Du \|_{L^2(\mathbb R^3)}^{1/2}  \| D^2 u \|_{L^2(\mathbb R^3)}^{1/2} $$

(This is sometimes called "Moser inequality")

Comment: Do you have any reference for such an inequality? Where did you learn it?

Comment: This inequality is part of a general family of Sobolev estimates of the form 

(1)   $ \;\, \| \, u \,\|_{L^{\infty}(\mathbb{R}^{n})}  \,\leq\; K \, \|\, D^{m-1} u \, \|_{L^{2}(\mathbb{R}^{n})}^{1/2} \, \|\, D^{m+1} u \,\|_{L^{2}(\mathbb{R}^{n})}^{1/2} \;\;\;\;$ if $n = 2\;\!m $, 

(2)   $\;\,  \| \, u \,\|_{L^{\infty}(\mathbb{R}^{n})}  \,\leq\; K \, \|\, D^{m} u \, \|_{L^{2}(\mathbb{R}^{n})}^{1/2} \, \|\, D^{m+1} u \,\|_{L^{2}(\mathbb{R}^{n})}^{1/2} \;\;\;\;$ if $n = 2\;\!m\,+\,1$.

Comment: See e.g. Prop. 3.8, Ch. 13, in Michael Taylor's book on PDEs (M. Taylor, Partial Differential Equations, vol. III, Springer, New York, 1996).
However, Taylor's proof provided there is inadequate: he simply claims the validity of an equivalent inquality, which seems just as hard to obtain.

Comment: Estimating the supnorm in terms of derivatives of low order is **very** important in PDE theory; in dimension $ n = 2m $ or $ n = 2m + 1 $, any such estimate in terms of L2 norms has to involve derivatives of order at least $ m + 1 $ (see Taylor's book, Ch. 13). 
For example, it is easy to derive the following Nirenberg-Gagliardo estimate: 

(3)   $\;\, \|\, u \,\|_{L^{\infty}(\mathbb{R}^{n})}  \,\leq\,   \|\, u \,\|_{L^{2}(\mathbb{R}^{n})}^{1/(m+1)} \,  \|\, D^{m+1} u \,\|_{L^{2}(\mathbb{R}^{n})}^{m/(m+1)} \;$ if $ n = 2m $,

and

Comment: (4)   $\;\, \|\, u \,\|_{L^{\infty}(\mathbb{R}^{n})}  \,\leq\,   \|\, u \,\|_{L^{2}(\mathbb{R}^{n})}^{1/(2m+2)} \,  \|\, D^{m+1} u \,\|_{L^{2}(\mathbb{R}^{n})}^{(2m+1)/(2m+2)} \;$ if $ n = 2m + 1 $.

Comment: In particular, the Moser estimates are very easy to show in dimension $ n = 1 $ or $ n = 2 $. The real difficulty starts in dimension $ n = 3 $: once this is obtained, it is likely that Moser's inequalities can be obtained for any $ n \geq 3 $ as well.

Comment: Actually, Moser's inequalities seem to be not really needed anywhere in analysis, since the much easier Gagliardo-Nirenberg inequalities (3), (4) above always do the job. So, the question I raised (about showing Moser's inequality in dimension $ n = 3 $, and hopefully also for any $ n \geq 3 $) is not really vital for anything; it is simply an intelectual question.

Comment: I looked at the papers by Moser and by Nirenberg. It seems that 1d inequalities usually suffice to cover the general case.

Comment: One last remark: (3), (4) are direct consequences of Prop. 2.4, Ch. 13, in Taylor's book (M. E. Taylor, Partial Differential Equations, vol. III, Springer, New York, 1996).

Comment: 1D inequalities can be very useful, true, but not in this case.